# first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: []

Tags: liveagent, chat

Following insert statement on PendingServiceRouting object is failing with this error : *`System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: []`*

I have checked, the service channel id and case object id & they are being set to valid id's. The error thrown by salesforce doesn't say which on which field the error is being thrown. Please post if any ideas to resolve this error

```
PendingServiceRouting psrObj = new PendingServiceRouting(
                CapacityWeight = 1,
                IsReadyForRouting = FALSE,
                RoutingModel = 'MostAvailable',
                RoutingPriority = 1,
                ServiceChannelId = svcChn.Id,
                WorkItemId = c.Id,
                PushTimeout = 0
        );
insert psrObj;
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Curiously, [Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/sforce_api_objects_pendingservicerouting.htm) says object isn't creatable although other doc says you must create it when doing SBR; also PushTimeout is not listed as a field in v46

Comment: @RenatoOliveira Full Error : System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: []

Comment: @cropredy I have both the test class and the apex class with business functionality in v45. By the way, this code only fails with test class. For normal user operations, it works fine.

Comment: So - the experiment to conduct is whether you can insert any PSR with the same fields (no more, no less) than you insert in PROD code. If YES - proceed from there; if NO, then you may need to mock this object  and modify your PROD code to use a selector layer and then mock the selector so you can unit test functionality.  See apexmocks and other dependency injection approaches

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same error trying to create a PSR for OmniChannel, and discovered that I had to include RoutingType field value for the PSR, and it had to be set to 'SkillsBased'. (I would get the error if I set RoutingType to QueueBased or ExternalRouting).